# Trying to sync two s3 buckets in lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am new to AWS and I am *trying to sync 2 s3 buckets*

this is the link to the origonal bucket
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/css490/input.txt

the original s3 bucket is public but not from my account
and the second one is also public but is an s3 from my account

I am using the test button in the top right and it says successful but program-4 (the receiving bucket) is still empty.

(it may be because I am using the test button, but I don't know)

plus how would I call this function in HTML?

**Responses To Comments:**

xy problem?:
I am syncing them because I need to copy the data from someone else's s3 bucket to my s3 bucket

**Note**: I need to overwrite data each time (even if the file exists)

The other link might have helped except it doesn't have an answer either
(I also asked that question btw)

```
import json
import boto3
import os
import subprocess



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # link the 2 s3 buckets
    subprocess(['aws', 's3', 'sync', 's3://css490', 's3://program-4'])
    
    #arn:aws:s3:::program-4

    return {
        'statusCode': 200
    }
```

Comment: "I am trying to sync 2 s3 buckets"—why? This is probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to download from (other persons public) s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65160555/trying-to-download-from-other-persons-public-s3-bucket)

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CLI is not installed by default in the Lambda environment.

See: [How to use AWS CLI within a Lambda function (aws s3 sync from Lambda) :: Ilya Bezdelev](https://bezdelev.com/hacking/aws-cli-inside-lambda-layer-aws-s3-sync/)

Also, you should use `subprocess.run()` to run a subprocess. I'm surprised you didn't see errors in the console about these problems.

While you could package the AWS CLI into a Lambda function, I would recommend simply performing the functions yourself:

- Use `ListBucket()` to list the source bucket
- Loop through the objects and use `CopyObject()` to copy each object to the destination bucket

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to copy, try this:
`aws s3 cp --recursive s3://SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME s3://SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME`